# Adding Firebase Admin SDK to Unity project

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Unity as well as to C# (real noob to C# and all the .NET stuff) and I want to use the Firebase Realtime Database in my Unity project.
I was following the instructions on the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start) to set things up, but after I created a new p12 file and added [this code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start#optional_editor_setup_for_restricted_access) to my project

```
  void Start() {
    // Set these values before calling into the realtime database.
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("YOUR-FIREBASE-APP-P12.p12");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("SERVICE-ACCOUNT-ID@YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("notasecret");
  }
```

I got the following hint:

> Method 'Firebase.Unity.Editor.FirebaseEditorExtensions.SetEditorP12FileName' is obsolete: Service account in editor is no longer supported. Please use standard sign-in methods instead, ex. FirebaseAuth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync()

This brought me to the [Firebase Deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/deprecated/deprecated) page which says:

[image: deprecation note]

Now I don't know how to add the Admin SDK to my Unity project. I can only find [references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) about how to add the Admin SDK to a server. But how can I add the Admin SDK to an Unity project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a mail to the Firebase Support and even wrote in the Firebase Community Slack channel and the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on how to add the Admin SDK to a server seems to be the way to go for unity projects as well.

Here is what I did (in case someone want to save some time):

1. I installed the [NuGet](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) plugin for Unity and then searched for the Firebase Admin SDK (installed the SDK of course as well)
2. I followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) and copied the code snippet into my project:

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
});
```

**Important**: after copying the code snippet and importing the dependencies, my IDE imported the `Firebase` package instead of the `FirebaseAdmin` package which of course don't work and the parameter `Credential` can't be found as part of `AppOptions`. So make sure to use the correct dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to write to some database locations from unity editor where you would not allow your regular user, you could **work around** it with firebase rules and setting up a "passkey".

In your unity script, add a passkey entry to the data (assuming they are represented by a dictionary `dict`) you are about to upload by `dict.Add("passkey", "12345");`. Additionally, put the code assigning the passkey value inside a conditional block which only compiles in the unity editor: `#if UNITY_EDITOR`, so that it does not make it into your app.

In your rules, set up a write condition in the relevant location as `{".read": false, ".write": "newData.child('passkey').val() === '12345'"}`.

However, I provide no guarantee that this is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to do the same thing. Unfortunaltely,FirebaseAdmin has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.0.0, but Unity has Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.0.0 built in. I tried a dependency-redirect. But i guess I am doing something wrong.

I created a "csc.rsp" file and added:

```
-appconfig:app.config
```

- I created a "app.config" file and added:

  ```
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" 
      publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" 
      newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      </configuration>
  ```

Did you stumble across the same issue?

Comment: As far as I can remember not.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33590898)