# Access Firebase From Unity Editor without affected by Database Rules?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I have been searching about this but could not find anything. I have database rules to manage user access, but also i want to access my database from Unity Editor without affected by these rules. Is there a way?

Comment: Create an admin like account and use it when in the Editor?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the Unity SDK to bypass the security rules. The only SDKs that Firebase provides that bypass the security rules are its [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), but those are not meant to be used on client-side applications. While there is an Admin SDK for C#/.NET, if you were to use this in a Unity app (which I'm not sure is possible) - you have to be really careful to not send this app to your users.

The idiomatic approach to implement admin functionality in your app, is by implementing the specific functionality as a custom aPI on a server or in Cloud Functions, and then:

1. Have your Unity app call that custom API.
2. On the server [verify who the user is](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and whether they are an application admin.
3. Perform the necessary operation using the Admin SDK.

Comment: On additional note, if you're a long time Firebase user then you might be used to using a service account in the editor. This has been deprecated for awhile and is now completely removed (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294552/adding-firebase-admin-sdk-to-unity-project). This answer is the best, and I would be very cautious about having the admin SDK anywhere close to your client code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out there is no way to achieve this and found another solution, created another firebase rtdb and connect it to the unity for editor use only. When i build for the stores i simply change the editorUrl to the other one.