# Using Firebase Admin SDK in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, nuget, firebase-admin

I am trying to follow this answer:
[Adding Firebase Admin SDK to Unity project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294552/adding-firebase-admin-sdk-to-unity-project/63327976#63327976)

But I can't get it to work.
I installed the nuget plugin for unity, I installed the firebase admin sdk package and I installed it's dependencies.
I get a bunch of errors that I don't know how to fix, and I am confused even though, the person in the thread says "just follow the instructions", it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some dependencies (System.Collections.Immutable). Since [this is provided by the system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-5.0), my recommended course of action would be to open Player Settings:
[image: Screenshot of the build window, a red arrow points to the "Player Settings" button in the lower left]

And change the "Api Compatibility Level*" under "Other Settings":
[image: Screenshot of the Api Compatibility Level menu, .NET 4.x is highlighted]

I think .NET 4.x might help (and .NET Standard 2.0 is default, and it looks like that's what's in the error log), but whatever you currently have selected try the opposite.

A final thing to try is to run this on a Windows machine if you're currently on Mac/Linux. Under some conditions, it will use the system .NET rather than the version of Mono that ships with Unity (I believe this is only the case for a UWP release build, but maybe it applies to the editor).

Comment: This kind of worked, the nuget manager still is a pain to deal with sometimes in unity. I actually found out the firebase admin sdk of c# isn't exactly what I want anyways, so now I switched to the javascript SDK and will build an external service.

Comment: I would also get really nervous about accidentally shipping admin logic to my final game . The JavaScript SDK is how I'd lean (and it might be easier to build an admin interface anyway, if you weren't relying on Unity for rendering bits of whatever tool you're building).